# how to update DaemonSet env variable value programmatically in golang

Tags: api, go, kubernetes, client-go

We have to update env variable value in the DaemonSet spec which is already deployed on k8s control plane.

Unfortunately we have no access to `kubectl` and only can use golang..

Perhaps we have to use https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go?

Comment: Yes that is possible

Comment: Thanks where we can find some examples?

Comment: @bogumbiker Could you explain why you would like an environment variable while a pod is running? Is it not allowed to change the env and restart the daemonset in your situation? What kind of daemonset are you using, e.g. fluentd?

Comment: The daemonset is only deployed on control  plane but not yet running as pod as there are no nodes. We have to change the env variable before nodes join the cluster.